# How do you group around a time period in active record, but only count one occurrance per user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

If I have a DailyCount table that tracks user activity, like so:

```
occurred_at | Sat, 04 Aug 2018
user_id     | 1

occurred_at | Sat, 04 Aug 2018
user_id     | 2

occurred_at | Fri, 03 Aug 2018
user_id     | 1
```

If I use groupdate, I can make a query like:

```
DailyCount.group_by_period('week', :occurred_at).count
```

And I'll get a result like:

```
Sun, July 29 2018=>3
```

But I'd like to have the user only counted once for that week.  Is there a way to do this either with the groupdate gem or without using datetrunc?

Comment: `DailyCount.group_by_period('week', :occurred_at).count('distinct(user_id)')`?

Comment: Think it would be worth having this as an answer, right?  Thx :)

Comment: Why did this get downvoted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DailyCount.group_by_period('week', :occurred_at).count('distinct(user_id)')
```

Comment: You can also end with `distinct.count(:user_id)`